# Iterative roots of sine

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

Is there an analytical function $f(z)$ such that $f(f(z)) = \sin(z)$? More generally, an analytical function such that f applied $n$ times to $z$ gives $\sin(z)$?

Is there a general theory for answering this question for functions besides $\sin(z)$?

Comment: You may find [this](http://mathoverflow.net/q/17614/21564) MathOverflow post helpful.

Comment: @JohnD.Cook also, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence/46765#46765 as was brought to my attention by Will Jagy in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189841/nonstandard-example-of-smooth-function-which-fails-to-be-analytic-on-mathbbr

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to numerically approximate such a function, assuming it exists. Let $f:(2\pi/n)Z_n \rightarrow (2\pi/n)Z_n$, for instance, with $f$ essentially an element in  $Z_n^n$ and we just seek to minimize $\sum |\sin(2\pi k/N)-f(f(2 \pi k/N))|^2$.

Comment: I've given some information on this in http://mathoverflow.net/a/45657/7710 . It also contains a general approach(using Carleman/Bell-matrices and matrix-logarithm). However, power series for such half-iterates might have convergence-radius zero and thus cannot conventionally be used. Sometimes a divergent summation procedure can be meaningful to arrive at a valid result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not analytic. On the real line it is $C^\infty$ and piecewise analytic. see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence/46765#46765 In the complex plane, the thing cannot even be defined in a neighborhood of the origin, as essential use is made of the logarithm. The final result is readily modified to give $n$-th iterative roots here, same conditions.

There is an entire discipline devoted to this. After the traditional names, Fatou, Leau, Julia, the modern names are Baker and Ecalle. I put a number of items as pdf's at [BAKER](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/other.html). I would like, someday, to see a translation of Ecalle's 1973 thesis.

Now, given a specific $x$ with $x_1 = \sin x$ and $ x_{n+1} = \sin x_n,$ we may take
$$ \alpha(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \; \left( \frac{3}{x_n^2}  \; + \; \frac{6 \log x_n}{5}  \; + \; \frac{79  x_n^2}{1050}   \; + \; \frac{29  x_n^4}{2625}  \; - \; n \right).$$

Note that $\alpha$ actually is defined on  $ 0 < x < \pi$ with
$\alpha(\pi - x) = \alpha(x),$ but the symmetry also means that the inverse function $\alpha^{-1}$ returns to the interval  $ 0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$ Meanwhile, $ \; \alpha(\sin x) = 1 + \alpha(x).$

Define
$$ f(x)  = \alpha^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \alpha(x)   \right) $$

Then $$  f(f(x)) = \sin x. $$

Note that $\alpha$ blows up at the origin. So, for $0 < x < \frac{1}{10},$ you might as well use the first half dozen terms of the asymptotic expansion I called $g$ in the MO question.

EDIT, MONDAY Aug 26:  it may help to point out that $\alpha$ is holomorphic in an open rhombus with opposite vertices at $0$ and $\pi,$ longer diagonal along the real axis, and $60^\circ$ angle at these two vertices. The rhombus is made up of two equilateral triangles. I have no idea how much larger a maximal domain of holomorphicity would be.

Answer (score 4):

Google the phrase "What you have to do twice in order to sin" (in quotes, verbatim) and you'll find a paper about this.

Comment: The Catholic Church's Council of Trent, meeting in the 1500s and issuing reactions against Protestantism, dogmatically decreed it to be a sin to get baptized more than once.  I suspect it was a reaction to the Anabaptists. But that's not what that paper is about.

Comment: OK, it now appears that this was a talk that someone gave, but Google will lead you to some pages that mention both that talk and some papers dealing with the problem.

Comment: Google results don't look the same for everyone.