# Integrating the Fabius function $q(x) = \int_0^x F(u) du$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, random-walk, smooth-functions

**There are any formulas for the integral of the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function)?**

*Context_____________*

After reading the following question: [Smooth functions that resemble random walks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368132/smooth-functions-that-resemble-random-walks), I started thinking about some examples and the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) comes into my mind: it is a smooth function that have lobes that switches from possitive to negative values following the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence), which is deterministic, but looks pretty random for the untrained viewer so I think about the changing patterns as seen in binary on the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) could easily represent an specific sequence of random variables that when added together will resemble a realization of an one dimensional [Random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk).

So following this idea, I think the integrating the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) $F(x)$ will lead to a function $q(x) = \int_0^x F(u) du$ that when seen from "far away" (zooming out enough, or conversely, scaling the variable $x$ by some positive quantity $a>0$ such we see $q\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$) will look like a realization of a random walk, but keeping the function as a smooth one.

*Attempts_________*

I have tried seen it numerically in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ube9ugsy6v) after doing some simplifications (approximating the Thue-Morse sequence and using $\sin(x)^4$ as the lobes), but is not powerfull enough to take the plots of the [integrated function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/piwwjofaej). Analitically, the Fabius function has some specific properties that have leads to some interpolation formulas for the lobes, which could be approximated as [shown in the links here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4710986/909869), but I don't have the skills to find the values of the integrated function. Maybe someone could do it or know some reference to a paper were it is done.

**Given $F(x)$ the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function), find $q(x)$ in:**
$$q(x) = \int\limits_0^x F(u)\ du$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fabius function satisfies the “functional differential equation” $$
F'(x) = 2 F(2x) \, ,
$$
therefore is
$$
\int_0^x F(u) \, du = \int_0^{x/2} 2 F(2t) \, dt = \int_0^{x/2} F'(t)\, dt 
= F(x/2) \, . 
$$

Comment: Whoa! Nice answer... I was expecting something that would start increasing and then decreasing randomly... I guess the Thue-Morse sequence works just like it does not happen and the function is kept doing lobes around zero.