# Question about the Thue-Morse Sequence and its relation with the Fabius function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, random-walk, smooth-functions

Recently, I made the following question [Integrating the Fabius function $q(x)=\int_0^x F(u)\ du$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4780252/909869) trying to make a function that would behave like a continuous smooth version of a [Random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) by integrating the smooth [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function), which lobes alternates from positive to negative values following the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence), so it could be imagined as a fixed realizations of a random variable taking two values (as is done when summing the binary $\pm1$ random variables to have a random walk).

But for my surprise, as shown by @MartinR [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4780262/909869):

> The Fabius function satisfies the “functional differential equation” $$
> F'(x) = 2 F(2x) \, ,
> $$
> therefore is
> $$
> \int_0^x F(u) \, du = \int_0^{x/2} 2 F(2t) \, dt = \int_0^{x/2} F'(t)\, dt 
> = F(x/2) \, . 
> $$

So we have again another scaled Fabius function, meaning that the sequence of lobes never accumulates such as the function lobes detaches from the x-axis.

I believe that this proves the following:

Let define the sequence $S(n)$ as:
$$S(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{\text{ThueMorse}[k]}$$
then $S(n)$ only can take the values $\{-1,\ 0,\ 1\}$ for all integer $n\geq 0$... $S(n)$ will never accumulates or add up to something different, even when [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28ThueMorse%5Bn%5D%29+%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+inf%7D%5D) says something against this,

**Is this $|S(n)| \leq 1, \forall n\geq 0$ conjecture true?**

Comment: Learned about the Fabius function from this question. Interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because if we split the Thue-Morse sequence into pairs, they all will be either $01$ or $10$, so for any even $n$ we have $S(n)=0$, and for odd $n$ $S(n)$ differs by $1$.

WolframAlpha is right when it says that the series diverges: it doesn't mean that it converges to $\infty$, it only means that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't noticed before that the TM series never have groups of contiguous ones or zeros bigger than $2$.