# What is the name of this type of interpolation/approximation? Piecewise tangent lines' sections / Fabius function example?

Tags: reference-request, approximation, special-functions, interpolation, approximation-theory

**What is the name of this type of interpolation/approximation? Piecewise tangent lines' sections / Fabius function example?**

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function, and let $\{x_i\}$ be a set of equidistant points such have a fixed difference value of $\Delta x=x_i-x_{i-1}$ which is constant for all index $i$.

Then the tangent line to any point of $f(x)$ at some value $x_i$ will be $f'(x_i)(x-x_i)+f(x_i)$, so one could make an interpolation approximation of $f(x)$ by joining these sections of tangent lines:
$$T(x) = \sum\limits_i \left( 
f'(x_i)(x-x_i)+f(x_i) \right)\cdot\frac{\left(\text{sgn}\left(x-x_i+\frac{\Delta x}{2}\right)-\text{sgn}\left(x-x_i-\frac{\Delta x}{2}\right)\right)}{2}$$

I know beforehand it could look something "obvious" or "stupid" since $T(x)$ is not continuous neither differentiable, as other existent interpolation alternatives do are like Splines or Taylor expansions, but I think on it because of the failing of Taylor series in fitting some smooth functions as is explained in the wiki [Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), as also no Power Series could represent accurately a [flat function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) since matching a constant violates the [Identity theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), but instead $T(x)$ will always converge to $f(x)$ if $f(x)$ is differentiable $|f'(x)|<\infty$, since if $\Delta x\to 0$ then $(x-x_i)|_{x\in\left[x_i-\frac{\Delta x}{2},\ x_i+\frac{\Delta x}{2}\right]}\to 0$ making $T(x)|_{x_i}=f(x_i)\Rightarrow T(x)\overset{\Delta x\to 0}{=} f(x)$.

With this, I could estimate the plot of the differentiable function $f(x)$ by using $T(x)$ if I know some values of $f(x)$ and corresponding values of $f'(x)$: as example, thinking in the case of the [Fabius function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) which "is an example of an infinitely differentiable function that is nowhere analytic", it should be possible to built $T(x)$ since its values at [dyadic numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), if I am not mistaken, in principle should be found as is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2090257/909869) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242326/909869).

So I would like to know:

1. The name of this kind of interpolation through tangent lines' secrions in order to look for them and see their properties.
2. It is possible to find $T(x)$ for the [Fabius function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function)?

---

*Motivation*

I am trying to understand if this kind of interpolation is what have been done on the approximation showed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285939/82135) for approximating the [Fabius function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) where the function's values are known only in some points (dense set of points).

---

*Added later*

The proposed interpolation looks alike the linear interpolation of two points, but with the difference that here the effective value of the derivative is used instead of its approximation: Are both related? Or equivalent?

I thought at first that the name would be easy to find since it is a really straightforward construction, but misteriously it don't show up on Google: I found [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324842?origin=crossref) by Alan Hurwitz where something really similar is done, but I couldn't figure out if it were exactly the same (my math skills are limited).

Here is a link to [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0p6nfb1ogc) were it can be seen that it kind of fit the function with enough "pieces", even with flat functions where Power Series should have difficulties.

[image: Image of the Desmos]

---

*2nd Added later - closing motivation part*

By playing in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fppuqbmgb8) that $T(x)$ only coincides with the construction done in the [mentioned answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285939/82135) at the first order when the fit is done with straight lines: for higher order they don't much being the other method much more inteligent since gives a continuos and differentiable fit, but $T(x)$ still get closer with smaller intervals.

[image: discrepancy between methods]

So now at least I know both scheemes are different each other.